# Как правильно использовать @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transaction

Изучаю Hibernate.

Я так понял, что транзакция гарантирует, что либо все данные этой транзакции будут сохранены, либо нет. Тогда логично использовать транзакции для операций, связанных с добавлением/обновлением данных в БД. Почему тогда я должен использовать аннотацию `@Transactional` для выполнения `SELECT`? Например:

**UserDAO:**

```
public class UserDAO {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public String getNameByUserId(int userId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select u.name from User u where u.id=:userId");
    ...
    ...
    return name;
    }
}
```

**UserService:**

```
public class UserService {
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Transactional
    public String getNameByUserId(int userId) {
        return userDAO.getNameByUserId(userId);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

Если я уберу `@Transactional`, то на строке  `Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` будет выброшено исключение. Я так понял, что в этом случае мне нужно делать `openSession()` и `close()` вручную? А как тогда работает `getCurrentSession()`?

Comment: Транзакционность нужна если вы вытягиваете сложный объект с коллекциями. А в вашем примере, будет работать и без неё.

Comment: @Vartlok Спасибо за ответ. Я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Когда вы используете `@Transactional` вы отдаете управление транзакциями спрингу(открытие-закрытие-роллбек и т.д.), если же вы не указываете, то должны сами всем управлять. `getCurrentSession()` берёт текущую транзакцию и возвращает её, в случае с аннотацией её создал спринг, без неё вы должны сами с этим разобраться.